# How do I create a recursive file list with md5sum in Linux and output to csv

Tags: linux, csv, terminal, ls, md5sum

I would like to list the files (ideally with an md5sum) within a directory and subdirectories in Ubuntu and output the results to a  csv file. I would like the output to be in the following format.

File Name, File Path, File Size (bytes), Created Date Time (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss), Modified Date Time (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss), md5sum

I have played around with the ls command but can seem to get the output correct. Is there  a better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the following script that outputs a CSV line for a given filepath argument:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eu

filepath=$1
qfilepath=${filepath//\\/\\\\}   # Quote backslashes.
qfilepath=${qfilepath//\"/\\\"}  # Quote doublequotes.

file=${qfilepath##*/}            # Remove the path.

stats=($(stat -c "%s %W %Y" "$filepath"))
size=${stats[0]}
ctime=$(date --date @"${stats[1]}" +'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
mtime=$(date --date @"${stats[2]}" +'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

md5=$(md5sum < "$filepath")
md5=${md5%% *}                   # Remove the dash.

printf '"%s","%s",%s,%s,%s,%s\n' \
    "$file" "$qfilepath" "$size" "$ctime" "$mtime" $md5
```

Now call it with

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -exec ~/csvline.sh {} \;
```

Note that the creation time is often not supported by the file system.