# How to extract the directory from full file path

Tags: linux, bash, dirname

I have the following script which prints various file stats, which was kindly supplied by another user (choroba) ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67822257/how-do-i-create-a-recursive-file-list-with-md5sum-in-linux-and-output-to-csv)).

Is there a way that this can be amended to report just the directory name of each file and not the full file path with the file name? I have tried changing filepath with dirname and I get a series of errors saying No such file or directory. Thanks for any advice.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eu

filepath=$1
qfilepath=${filepath//\\/\\\\}   # Quote backslashes.
qfilepath=${qfilepath//\"/\\\"}  # Quote doublequotes.

file=${qfilepath##*/}            # Remove the path.

stats=($(stat -c "%s %W %Y" "$filepath"))
size=${stats[0]}
ctime=$(date --date @"${stats[1]}" +'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
mtime=$(date --date @"${stats[2]}" +'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

md5=$(md5sum < "$filepath")
md5=${md5%% *}                   # Remove the dash.

printf '"%s","%s",%s,%s,%s,%s\n' \
        "$file" "$qfilepath" "$size" "$ctime" "$mtime" $md5
```

Comment: _I have tried changing filepath with dirname_ : Where in the code posted is the invocation of `dirname`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `dirname` and `basename`, where:

`dirname` will strip the last component from the full path;

`basename` will get the last component from the path.

So to summarize: `$(basename $(dirname $qfilepath))` will give you the name of the last directory in the path.
Or, for the full path without the file name - just `$(dirname $qfilepath)`.

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not see anything in the script snippet which would produce a recursive list, you can get the directory name output with adding `dir=$(dirname $filepath)` and modifying your printf output to use `$dir` instead of `$file`.